# proving we can approx the value $ |\sum_{n=1}^{p}a_{n}b_{n}-S| $ using Abel's sum formula

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Assume $ a_n,b_n $ 2 series such: for every $ p\in N$ exists $ M>0 $ such that : $ |S_{p}|=|\sum_{n=1}^{p}a_{n}|\leq M $ and $ b_n $ monotonic decreasing and coverging to 0. let $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}b_{n} $

and prove that $ |\sum_{n=1}^{p}a_{n}b_{n}-S|\leq2Mb_{p+1} $

so far i managed  to get here : $ |\sum_{n=1}^{p}a_{n}b_{n}-S|\leq  |S_{p}b_{p+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{p}S_{n}\left(b_{n}-b_{n+1}\right)-S| $ using Abel's sum formula. i dont know how to proceed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Employ Abel's method to the tail instead:
\begin{align*}
& \left| {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^p {a_n b_n }  - S} \right| = \left| {\sum\limits_{n = p + 1}^\infty  {a_n b_n } } \right| = \left| {S_p b_{p + 1}  - \sum\limits_{n = p + 1}^\infty  {S_n (b_n  - b_{n + 1} )} } \right|
\\ &
 \le \left| {S_p b_{p + 1} } \right| + \sum\limits_{n = p + 1}^\infty  {\left| {S_n } \right|(b_n  - b_{n + 1} )}  \le Mb_{p + 1}  + \sum\limits_{n = p + 1}^\infty  {M(b_n  - b_{n + 1} )}  = 2Mb_{p + 1} .
\end{align*}

Comment: I see. Im trying to evaluate $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n} $ using what we found so that the mistake will be less then $ 10^-3 $ so i found that $ \sum_{n=1}^{1999}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n} $ will be close enough, using what we found. any ideas how can i calculate it?

Comment: In "J. M. Borwein, P. B. Borwein, K. Dilcher, Pi, Euler Numbers, and Asymptotic Expansions, The American Mathematical Monthly. 96 (1989), 681–687." the authors derived approximations for the tail of this series. In particular, they found that $$
\sum\limits_{k = N + 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{k}}  = ( - 1)^{N + 1} \left( {\frac{1}{{2N}} - \frac{1}{{4N^2 }} + r_N } \right),\quad \left| {r_N } \right| \le \frac{1}{{8N^3 }}.
$$ Employing this with $N=1999$, it is found that the error is at most $0.0002500625\ldots$.